# Issue with JavaScript quiz if radi is checked

Tags: javascript

Below it's my code that I made and I do not want to skip the question without checking any option from the question when I press button Next and I tried by using: checked as the code below shows, but it does not work.
And also it does not show quiz results when I finish the quiz and click the Submit button, it does not show results how many questions I got correct like the JS code is?

```
<div id = "results">
      <form id="quiz-form">
          <div class="quiz">
            <div id="pytja1" class="questions1">
              <span class="quest1">I am a ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="male" id="correct"> Male<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="female" id="correct2"> Female<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="other"> Other<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja2" class="questions2">
              <span class="quest2">Football has letters ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="8" class="correct"> 8<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5"> 5<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="6"> 6<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja3" class="questions3">
              <span class="quest3">VW stands for ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="BMW" /> BMW <br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Volkswagen" class="correct" /> Volkswagen<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Audi" /> Audi<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja4" class="questions4">
              <span class="quest4">What year it is ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2017" /> 2017<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2015" /> 2015<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2019" class="correct" /> 2019<br/>
              <input id="bot-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

```
form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.quiz {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 460px;
  left: 42%;
}

.quest1,
.quest2,
.quest3,
.quest4 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.questions1 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.questions2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.questions3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.questions4 {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

.bot {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#pytja2,
#pytja3,
#pytja4 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```
let question1 = document.getElementById('pytja1');
let question2 = document.getElementById('pytja2');
let question3 = document.getElementById('pytja3');
let question4 = document.getElementById('pytja4');
let result = document.getElementById('bot-submit');
let nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.bot');

for (let i = 0; i < nextButtons.length; i++) {
  let nextQuestion = nextButtons[i];
  nextQuestion.onclick = function() {
    switchToNextQuestion(this);
  };
}

function switchToNextQuestion(nextQuestion) {
  let parentId = nextQuestion.parentNode.id;
  if (parentId === 'pytja1') {
    question1.style.display = 'none';
    question2.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja2') {
    question2.style.display = 'none';
    question3.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja3') {
    question3.style.display = 'none';
    question4.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function radioChecked(form) {
    let checked = form.querySelector("input[type=radio]:checked");
    let value;
    if (!checked) {
        alert("You need to select one option");
        return;
    } else {
        value = checked.value;
    }
    results.push(value);
}

    let questions = [
        {
              prompt: "I am a ?\n(a) Male\n\ (b) Female\n(c) Others",
              answer: "a"
        },
        {
             prompt: "Football has letters ?\n(a) 8\n\ (b) 5\n(c) 6",
             answer: "a"
        },
        {
             prompt: "VW stands for ?\n(a) BMW \n\ (b) Volkswagen\n(c) Audi",
             answer: "b"
        },
        {
            prompt: "What year it is ?\n(a) 2017 \n\ (b) 2015\n(c) 2019",
            answer: "c"
       }
   ];

   let score = 0;

   for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        let response = window.prompt(questions[i].prompt);
        if(response == questions[i].answer){
             score++;
             alert("Correct!");
        } else {
             alert("WRONG!");
        }
   }

   alert("you got " + score + "/" + questions.length);
document.getElementById("bot-submit").addEventListener("click", 
function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: You really should never use `eval` more or less in any situation

Comment: @SterlingArcher any reason why? Slows the speed of browser or what reasons so I can avoid in the future?

Comment: To rid yourself of eval, the simple solution is don't set the var instead just access the form field value instead with the variable: `document.forms["quiz-form"]["q" + i].value`

Comment: @Behar using `eval` introduces a security vulnerability into your script -- eval on a nutshell executes a string as JS, so by using eval, you are exposing users the ability to exploit it

Comment: @SterlingArcher got rid of eval and used i++ and still does not work ?

Comment: _“and still does not work ?”_ - well then do some … debugging? Your browser dev tools allow you to step through your code as it is executing. (If you need more help/advice on basic debugging, then please go research that on your own.)

Comment: @04FS Such a nice help from you, thank you a lot!
I came here because there were no errors in Console Log and with searching could not find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is what you want. You have a lots of unnecessary code but i'm not getting into that now. You just needed the questions array for the window prompt to work.

```js
let question1 = document.getElementById('pytja1');
let question2 = document.getElementById('pytja2');
let question3 = document.getElementById('pytja3');
let question4 = document.getElementById('pytja4');
let result = document.getElementById('bot-submit');
let nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.bot');
let currentQues;
for (let i = 0; i < nextButtons.length; i++) {
  let nextQuestion = nextButtons[i];
  nextQuestion.onclick = function() {
    switchToNextQuestion(this);
  };
}

function switchToNextQuestion(nextQuestion) {
  let parentId = nextQuestion.parentNode.id;
  if (parentId === 'pytja1') {
    question1.style.display = 'none';
    question2.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja2') {
    question2.style.display = 'none';
    question3.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja3') {
    question3.style.display = 'none';
    question4.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function radioChecked(form) {
    let checked = form.querySelector("input[type=radio]:checked");
    let value;
    if (!checked) {
        alert("You need to select one option");
        return;
    } else {
        value = checked.value;
    }
    results.push(value);
}

    let questions = [
        {
              prompt: "I am a ?\n(a) Male\n\ (b) Female\n(c) Others",
              answer: "a"
        },
        {
             prompt: "Football has letters ?\n(a) 8\n\ (b) 5\n(c) 6",
             answer: "a"
        },
        {
             prompt: "VW stands for ?\n(a) BMW \n\ (b) Volkswagen\n(c) Audi",
             answer: "b"
        },
        {
            prompt: "What year it is ?\n(a) 2017 \n\ (b) 2015\n(c) 2019",
            answer: "c"
       }
   ];

   let score = 0;

   for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        let response = window.prompt(questions[i].prompt);
        console.log(response);
        if(response == questions[i].answer){
             score++;
             alert("Correct!");
        }
        else if(response !== questions[i].answer && response !== 'a' && response !== 'b' && response !== 'c'){
         alert("You need to select one option");
         i--;
         
         }
        
         else {
             alert("WRONG!");

        }
   }

   alert("you got " + score + "/" + questions.length);
document.getElementById("bot-submit").addEventListener("click", 
function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.quiz {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 460px;
  left: 42%;
}

.quest1,
.quest2,
.quest3,
.quest4 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.questions1 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.questions2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.questions3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.questions4 {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

.bot {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#pytja2,
#pytja3,
#pytja4 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "results">
      <form id="quiz-form">
          <div class="quiz">
            <div id="pytja1" class="questions1">
              <span class="quest1">I am a ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="male" id="correct"> Male<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="female" id="correct2"> Female<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q1" value="other"> Other<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja2" class="questions2">
              <span class="quest2">Football has letters ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="8" class="correct"> 8<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5"> 5<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q2" value="6"> 6<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja3" class="questions3">
              <span class="quest3">VW stands for ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="BMW" /> BMW <br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Volkswagen" class="correct" /> Volkswagen<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q3" value="Audi" /> Audi<br/>
              <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
            </div>
            <div id="pytja4" class="questions4">
              <span class="quest4">What year it is ?</span><br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2017" /> 2017<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2015" /> 2015<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2019" class="correct" /> 2019<br/>
              <input id="bot-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see it works with window prompt so I will try to make this work without prompt and alert me when I skip questions from HTML elements, thank you

Comment: and if you have time to reply could you tell me which line of codes is not unnecessary so I can shorten it?

Comment: Your program is divided in to two parts. One is a html form. The other is a window prompt which is being used as a form. As of now only the window prompt part is being executed. You should separate the two.

You don't need the part from `let questions = [ ....` to the end of for loop in javascript code to make the html part work.  This part is what runs when you run the snippet.


Now to make the html part work you need to assign action in form element. Or you can remove `type=submit` from the button and assign a handler to handle button click.

Comment: Forgive me for this comment but I am trying to remove window.prompt so it would not show the question on an alert prompt but instead, it will show on HTML elements as I did on the code below and if I try to go to the next question without selecting any option from the question it will alert that I need to select an option. I tried to change the code like below on Codepen but still, I can skip questions without selecting any option, any idea where's my code wrong?
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/byGMrY

Comment: You haven't used `document.forms` properly. The console has a few errors. Try resolving them first. Read up on Document.forms here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms.
As far as the making answer to every question compulsory is concerned, check whether an option has been selected or not with radioChecked function and return true if an option is checked, return false and display the alert.